# Interpreting Probability Statements

Tags: probability

How would you interpret the following line:

> "What is the probability that a 90s song from Sam's iPod is not a pop song"

Would you choose either,

$a)$ "The probability of being not a pop song given it's from the 90s"

$b)$ "The probability of being not a pop song and from the 90s"

I can't make a distinction between the two. Which one, in your opinion is correct, and why?

Comment: It is option a).  It must not a pop song if it is a 90´s song. The text for option b) would be like:" What is the probability that  song from Sam's iPod is not a pop song and from the 90`s"

Answer (score 1):

I would go with (a). The wording seems to imply that we are given that the song will be from the 90s. In other words, the sample space is the set of 90s songs on Sam's iPod.

Comment: So basically, since the probability of you getting a pop song depends on the probability you get a 90's song - it should be (a)?

Comment: In the question, we are told there's two era's of interest. The 90's and 00's. We are told that 25% of his total songs are pop songs. Of that, 20% of his total songs are pop from the 90's, while while the remaining 5% are from the 00's. So from this you can infer that the probability of getting a pop song changes with the era we're talking about?

Comment: @Philip  You should open a different post for a different question not ask in comments.